# How Can I change the width of master view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I'm developing an article reading app.
In iPad,i am using Split view controller.
How can I change the width of master view controller.

Answer (score 1):

try this may be help full ..

```
[splitViewController setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:200.0] forKey:@"_masterColumnWidth"];
```

Thanks & Cheers ..

Comment: @ Joge thanks!this code i have to put in app delegate or in class of master view controller

Comment: @ Joge it gives error:                                                            Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ysMasterViewController 0xb1bc> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _masterColumnWidth.'

Comment: Are you trying in your UISplitViewController

Comment: I try this in viewDidload of master view controller class that is ysMasterViewController